# How to lower tx fees for my erc 20 token in solidity

Tags: ethereum, solidity

so i have created an erc 20 token and I was hoping to find out how I could make it lower the tx fee by 50 percent for all holders. So I have just some base code. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an off-the-self ER20 contract, there's not going to be much you can do to lower the gas usage.

If it is a contract you wrote yourself, the only area likely to allow for that size of improvement would be if you had a lot of complex logic and writes and were able to remove much of the extra complexity.